# Date in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I have a form field in my Rails view:

`<%= f.date_select :Date_of_Birth %>`

This shows a drop down menu with only the last 10 years and I need to go back to 1800. Better if I could just type the year in rather than have a 200 item drop down list. I also need the option not to fill in the date, that is, blank.

I have found a couple of hints here in stackoverflow, but they don't use quite this format which was generated for me. Suspect because I'm using Rails 4.

Comment: What happens when you pass it a placeholder value?  date_field("user", "born_on", value: "1984-05-12")

Comment: I'm not following where I would do this. I'm very much a newbie to Rails and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to extend the range of selection:

```
<%= f.date_select :Date_of_Birth, start_year: 1800, end_year: Time.now.year %>
```

Having a text input field for the year is not so easy but it could be done, by adding `discard_year: true` to the `date_select`.

Then you add a text field tag AFTER the date_select inputs with a special name like `name_of_your_object_Date_of_Birth(1i)` where "name_of_your_object" is the name you used in the `form_for` tag. Inspect the HTML fields which `date_selects` generates in your browser.

Comment: Thank you. The first suggestion solves one problem. Well two problems. With the date in range, one can type the date instead of selecting it (and of course now the dates are in the range I want).

But I can't leave the date blank on the form and I don't always have the information. 

Maybe I'll generate two edit or entry forms, one without the date since I usually don't need it and another with the date.

But I'll look at your second suggestion too. I have to think about it.

Comment: <%= f.date_select :Date_of_Birth, start_year: 1800, end_year: Time.now.year, :include_blank => true %>